# How to access running python in vagrant from host machine browser?

Tags: python, vagrant

I installed Vagrant in windows, now I have a virtual ubuntu , I run a python script :

```
vagrant@precise32:/vagrant/FlaskMysql/FlaskApp$ ls
app.py  static  storedPro.txt  templates
vagrant@precise32:/vagrant/FlaskMysql/FlaskApp$ python app.py
* Running on http://127.0.0.1:5002/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

my Vagrantefile :

```
config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise32"
  config.vm.provision :shell, path: "bootstrap.sh"
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 4567
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 5002, host: 5002
```

I tried to access the above address from the browser in my window, the index.html page appears in a couple of seconds then disappears.

UPDATE :

```
vagrant@precise32:/vagrant/FlaskMysql/FlaskApp$ curl http://127.0.0.1:5000
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>500 Internal Server Error</title>
<h1>Internal Server Error</h1>
<p>The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your   request.  Either the server is overloaded or
there is an error in the application.</p>
```

Thanks.

Comment: your host machine needs  to forward 5002 to the guest machines port 5002?

Comment: I already added : config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 5002, host: 5002   but still getting  : This webpage is not available

Answer (score 3):

In addition to forwarding the port you'll need to run the Flask app with host `"0.0.0.0"`:

```
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5002)
```

This makes the dev server externally visible; in the case of Vagrant, we want the app to be externally visible (from the guest OS to the host OS).

Comment: I changed it to app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5002) as you said, and when I went to   http://0.0.0.0:5002/  I always get : This webpage is not available

Comment: @BouchaibMounir From a browser on your host machine you'll go to `http://127.0.0.1:5002` to access the site.

Comment: I added an UPDATE in my question, curl.

Comment: NOW when I tried to access 127.0.0.1:5000 from the browser in my window, the index.html page appears, when I click in a link it disappears and when I refresh the page it disappears,

Comment: @BouchaibMounir you are serving the app on port 5002, not 5000. Either you need to serve the app on port 5000 or you need to update your curl to hit port 5002

Comment: Mine is : app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to chucksmash's answer, this is my version of the solution:

I changed the host and port in the **Python App** from this:

```py
run(host='localhost', port=8080, debug=True)
```

to this:

```py
run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5002, debug=True)
```

---

and in the **vagrantfile** from this:

```
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8080, host: 8080, host_ip: "127.0.0.1"
```

to this:

```
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 5002, host: 5002
```

then test a request and **do NOT forget to add the resource (URL endpoint)** 'hello' in my example: `http://0.0.0.0:5002/hello`

this fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I want to add more to Chucksmash's answer, if anyone is still facing issues with connecting to flask URL on host machine. Try one of these options (both should work):

**Vagrantfile:**

```
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 5000, host: 5000, host_ip: "127.0.0.1"
```

**app.py:**

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return "Hello world!"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

**Method 1.** Configure host and port in app.run() and run the flash app using python.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=5000)
```

Run flask app:

```
$ python3 app.py
```

**Method 2.** Pass `host` and `port` as arguments to `flask run`:

```
export FLASK_APP=app.py
flask run --host "0.0.0.0" --port 5000
```

You can verify if it works by running the following on terminal:

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:5000
```

*output*: `Hello world!`